# "Required request body is missing: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<?>

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman

I am learning Spring-Boot features and going through them also with Postman. But when i run the code i get 400 Bad Request Error on Postman like this: 
"Required request body is missing: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity". Have i missed an attribute or the coding is all the way wrong?

```
 @RestController
 @RequestMapping("/api/board")
 @CrossOrigin
public class ProjectTaskController {

@Autowired
private ProjectTaskService projectTaskService;

@PostMapping("")
public ResponseEntity<?> addPTToBoard( @Valid @RequestBody ProjectTask projectTask, BindingResult result){
    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        Map<String, String> errorMap= new HashMap<>();

        for(FieldError error: result.getFieldErrors()) {
            errorMap.put(error.getField(), error.getDefaultMessage());
        }
         return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>>(errorMap, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    ProjectTask newPT= projectTaskService.saveOrUpdateProjectTask(projectTask);
    return new ResponseEntity<ProjectTask>(newPT, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

The projectTask code, it has getters and setters also.

```
@Entity
public class ProjectTask {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@NotBlank(message = "summary cannot be blank")
private String summary;
private String acceptanceCriteria;
private String status;

public ProjectTask() {

}
```

[Postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57BUX.jpg) Here

Comment: can you add your http request ? are you sure you are passing the request body ?

Comment: @NaderHajlaoui i have updated my question

Comment: you need to provide the request body, otherwise you'll always have 400 bad request. because when you look at your endpoint signature `@Valid @RequestBody ProjectTask projectTask` we clearly see that a `projectTask` is needed as input.

Comment: @NaderHajlaoui how can i provide what u said?

Comment: when you call your endpoint, you have to provide the request body, if you're using postman, you need to put some data in the body as `application/json`, please refer to my answer, i provided a sample request code, you can import it in your postman.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a @PostMapping you need to make a postman POST request like this:
[image]

make sure to select `raw` and content type of `application/json` along with a json object for the body of the request

Comment: @rediramaj you still need to add a json object to your request body. I think it will work with an empty one as well. eg {}

Comment: it wont work with empty json body, because we have constraint on `summary`
`@NotBlank(message = "summary cannot be blank")`

Comment: I've updated the screenshot. try adding that json object to the body of the request

Comment: @PPetkov should i add in the method or the projecttask class?

Comment: you add it to your HTTP request in Postman as the request body

Comment: @PPetkov not quite following you sorry

Comment: copy the request from the screenshot above exactly as you see it @rediramaj

Answer (score 0):

Redi here's a sample request :

```
curl -X POST \
  'http://>>>> your endpoint url' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
"summary" : "sample summary",
"acceptanceCriteria" : "blabla",
"status" : "fake status"
}'
```

Comment: can you please validate the answer

Answer (score 0):

That's right..! Yeah you are sending a bad request. You have to send request payload in POST request.

**Solution :** 
While sending the POST request please send with body like this in your case.

```
{
"summary":"any",
"acceptance":"any",
"status":"any"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps, hope it'll work:

1. Open Postman and locate the "Import" button located on the top left corner.
2. Click on the "Import" button and select the "Paste Raw Text" option.
3. In the text field that appears, paste the curl command I've provided below:

```
curl --location 'http://localhost:8080/api/board' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data '{
        "summary": "Sample summary",
        "acceptanceCriteria": "Sample acceptance criteria",
        "status": "Sample status"
    }'
```

4. Click the "Continue" button to import the curl command.
5. Adjust the sample values in the JSON request body (summary, acceptanceCriteria, and status) with your own data.
6. Finally, click the "Send" button to make the POST request to `http://localhost:8080/api/board`.